# Staret managed server using Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I am trying to start web-logic managed server from Linux system. for that I have one shell script `start_wls_managed4_btwnpmd01.sh` with following code.

> /folder-name1/folder-name2/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh managed4_name01
>   &

`startManagedWebLogic.sh` - is my managed server start script name and

`managed4_name01` - is my managed server name

when I trying to execute `start_wls_managed4_btwnpmd01.sh` file it giving me following issue.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /wls_domains/btwnpmd01
[btwnpmd01] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4159729533839156707.sh
+ start_wls_managed4_btwnpmd01.sh
/wls_domains/btwnpmd01/Jenkins/CIProjects/MeasCapability/properties
***************************************************
.
CLASSPATH=/wls_domains/btwnpmd01/Jenkins/CIProjects/MeasCapability/properties:/wls_domains/btwnpmd01/Jenkins/CIProjects/MeasCapability/lib/**list of jar file names in project**
.
MEM_ARGS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85
.
JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/cacerts  -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=/software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/wlserver_10.3/server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=false -Dweblogic.management.server=http://10.54.9.26:61000  -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true -Dweblogic.unicast.HttpPing=true -Dweblogic.jms.IsolateBridgeThreadPool=true -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:/wls_domains/btwnpmd01/logs/mps/managed4_btwnpmd01_gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/wls_domains/btwnpmd01/logs/mps
.
Redirecting logs to /folder-name1/folder-name2/logs/mps/managed4_btwnpmd01_stdout.log
***************************************************
Finished: SUCCESS
```

When I check the log file at `/folder-name1/folder-name2/logs/mps/managed4_btwnpmd01_stdout.log` location then it was blank.

It is not able to start managed server, where I am going wrong? can you please assist me?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write a file in that directory? You are running as user *anonymous*.

Comment: I have permissions for write a file, when I execute same from `cmd` its working fine.